# Concurrent dictionary Lazy<T> delegate is being invoked multiple times

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, lazy-loading, concurrentdictionary

I am trying to use `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,Lazy<T>>` to get a token and cache it in-memory. The `GetToken()` method contains logic to read existing tokens from database, check for token expiry and make an HTTP call to refresh the token if the existing token has expired.

```cs
public static class TokenCache
{
   private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<Token>> _tokens = new 
   ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<Token>>();

   private static int dbCount = 0;

   public static Token GetToken(int id)
   {
        // Get the lazy token object
        Lazy<Token> lazyToken= _tokens.GetOrAdd(id, key => new Lazy<Token>(() =>
        {
            var token=GetTokenFromDB(id);

            Interlocked.Increment(ref dbCount);
            Console.WriteLine("GetOrAdd " + dbCount);

            if ((token.ExpiryDate - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes <= 5)
            {
                _tokens.TryRemove(id, out _); 
                return RefreshToken(id, cred);
            }
            
            return token;
        }));

        // Access the token
        return lazyToken.Value;
    }
}
```

```cs
Parallel.For(1, 100, _ => TokenCache.GetToken(555));
```

My understanding is if two threads simultaneously call `GetToken()` and then the `GetOrAdd()` method, it will create two `Lazy<Token>` objects but at this point no database call and HTTP call is made yet. The db calls (and token refresh HTTP request) are invoked when we call `.Value` and thus we will be having a single db call and token refresh even when there are multiple threads. However, when I tested this, I am seeing that the delegate inside `Lazy<Token>` is being invoked 5-7 times when about 100 threads are run parallelly.

Shouldn't the delegate for `Lazy<T>` be invoked only once?

Comment: @Elish I can't reproduce that after changing `.Minutes` to `.TotalMinutes`. Are you sure your tokens have long enough `ExpiryDate`?

Comment: @freakish tokens have a TTL of 60 mins. The delegate logs the number of times it is invoked (edited the question to reflect this) and I can still see multiple invocation after changing to `.TotalMinutes`.

Comment: *`Console.WriteLine("GetOrAdd " + dbCount);`* -- It's better to log the value returned atomically by the `Interlocked.Increment`, instead of accessing again the shared static field.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand the logic of your code. The `valueFactory` of the `Lazy<Token>` is invoked only once. In case it is invoked at a time that the token is expired, it will evict the `id` from the dictionary, hopefully evicting the same `Lazy<Token>` instance. In case the token has not expired, the token will stay in the dictionary forever. In which scenario is this behavior desirable?

Comment: I can't reproduce that after the change from `.Minutes` to `.TotalMinutes`. IMO that was the reason for the code not working (plus I agree with @TheodorZoulias that the design is bad). I'm voting to close the question.